# Kill a process by PID started by Batch Script (avoiding other process of same name)

Tags: command-line, process, cmd.exe, kill

I have multiple processes by the same name (say multiple FIREFOX.exe process). A Batch script then opens another firefox.exe process and, after some predefined time, needs to kill the process it opened.

I had the following solution for it

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -P "ABC" -no-remote
PING 127.0.0.1 -n 10 -w 1000 >NUL
for /F "TOKENS=1,2,*" %%a in ('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq firefox.exe"') do set MyPID=%%b
taskkill /PID %MyPID% /T
```

**This works fine EXCEPT** if another process by the same  name (firefox.exe) opens after the 1st command (i.e running firefox), the taskkill command actually kills the latest process instead of the one it started

**So how do i make sure the script only kills the process it started and none other.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway i solved the issue myself.

**Actually, the solution above itself needs a small tweak.** Thats all

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -P "ABC" -no-remote
for /F "TOKENS=1,2,*" %%a in ('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq firefox.exe"') do set MyPID=%%b    
PING 127.0.0.1 -n 10 -w 1000 >NUL
taskkill /PID %MyPID% /T
```

**What was earlier happening was** i was setting the %MyPID%  after the PING command (which is just a time delay). So in that period, any new process( with same name) which opened, got its PID registered for taskkill.  I just simply moved the command immediately after the process opening command and  now it works.

**Technically, though,** if there are too many same processes opening (say within milliseconds), by multiple scripts, this can still cause issues and taskill can kill wrong process (May be someone can write a answer about that. i will not accept my answer as of now...but will wait for a day or 2, for that) :)

Comment: you could use `wmic` to start a process (FF in your instance) and get its PID: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618914/getting-process-id-of-exe-running-in-bat-file